# UITableView horizontal scroll indicator

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a table view inside a navigation controller, which is one view for a tab bar.

Everytime I launch the app, the horizontal scroll indicator flashes briefly when i select this tab.

Could this be related to the initial tab selected, which does contain a scrollview?

I was under the impression that table views couldn't scroll horizontally?

It doesnt seem to affect the app, just annoying thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Do you do programmatic scrolling in your view?

We did this flashing on purpose in one of our apps, using some code to set a new scroll position (0) with animation enabled.

EDIT: There is also the method: flashScrollIndicators in UIScrollView (a UITableView also being a UIScrollView).

Comment: I do programmatic scrolling on my first tab, which contains a normal scrollview. Switching to the third tab, contains just a tableview inside a nav controller. I would like a flashScrollIndicators:NO method to prevent this flashing. Thanks.

Comment: I've had a weird problem yersterday with a TableView. I tried to use Content Insets (in IB) to setup some inner margins. It ended up messing with horizontal scrolling (although it was disabled) in bizarre ways. Disabling (setting to 0) content insets fixed it.